# Link to fancybox content

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Not quite sure how to explain this the best way, but i'll give it a go!

I have a php site that uses Fancybox. At the moment, if anyone clicks Login, an overlay appears with the login form. If someone clicks to post a new listing and they're not logged in, I'd like the fancybox overlay to appear again, allowing a user to login.

At the moment, I have a couple lines of php code that check if a session is active - if not, it redirects to a login page, I want this to activate a fancybox popup with the login form... if possible?

I'm not sure how best to achieve this? Any help would be awesome! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what programing language you are writing in besides jQuery, but a high-level solution might be to drop a cookie when the user logs in. Then, when they click to post a new listing, check for that cookie. If it's there, let them post. If not show the login window. Here's some pseudo code using the [jQuery.Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin:

```
$(function(){
$('.login-button').click(function(){
    //send login info via ajax
  $(this).hide("slow",function(){
    // drop a cookie
    $.cookie( 'login', '1',  { expires: 1, path: '/' } );
  });
});

// When the post button is clicked, check for the cookie
// If there's no cookie, show the login box
$('.post-button').click(function(){       
    if( $.cookie('Login') === null ) { 
        $("#login-box").fancybox();
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
 });

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using php. My function at the moment to check if someone is logged in is:

if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){  
    header("location:/login/");
 }

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways of doing so.

First of all, how are you identifying that someone is logged in? Suppose if I can do so with an if condition:

```
if(user==null) {
  //no login
}
```

I can trigger the click of anchor link for **LOGIN** and thus, open the fancybox again.

```
if(user==null) {
  $("a#login").trigger('click');
}
```

Hope it gives you some help.